# springboot mysql docker windows7

Tags: mysql, maven, docker, spring-boot

OS- Windows 7

Docker version : Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24302

Springboot version: 1.5.3.RELEASE

I have taken codebase from https://github.com/TechPrimers/docker-mysql-spring-boot-example (This is working sample code in MacOS.)

My application.properties looks like below

```
# DataSource settings: set here your own configurations for the database
# connection. In this example we have "netgloo_blog" as database name and
# "root" as username and password.
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://mysql-standalone:3306/test
spring.datasource.username = testuser
spring.datasource.password = testuserpass

# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager)

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

server.port=8086
```

Dockerfile looks like below

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/users-mysql.jar users-mysql.jar
EXPOSE 8086
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "users-mysql.jar"]
```

1. Use MySQL Image published by Docker Hub (https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)
   Command to run the mysql container

   docker run --name mysql-standalone -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpass -e MYSQL_DATABASE=test -e MYSQL_USER=testuser -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=testuserpass -d mysql:5.6

I see docker mysql container named mysql-standalone.

2. Using the Dockerfile create the Docker image.
   From the directory of Dockerfile -

   docker build . -t users-mysql

I see docker image created users-mysql

3. Run the Docker image (users-mysql) created in #3.

docker run -p 8086:8086 --name users-mysql --link mysql-standalone:mysql -d users-mysql

I see application running in docker container named users-mysql

4. I try to visit http://localhost:8086/all/ 
   I get error:

This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.

5. I tried to check logs of application "users-mysql" and mysql container "mysql-standalone"
   However, I don't see any error or exception there.

Am I doing something wrong?

Based on some comments I thought of adding application start logs.

```
2018-05-17 20:52:29.921  INFO 1 --- [           main] SpringDataJpaHibernateExampleApplication : Starting SpringDataJpaHibernateExampleApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT o
n b4f3a2acd0a9 with PID 1 (/users-mysql.jar started by root in /)
2018-05-17 20:52:29.937  INFO 1 --- [           main] SpringDataJpaHibernateExampleApplication : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-05-17 20:52:30.124  INFO 1 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConf
igEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5b37e0d2: startup date [Thu May 17 20:52:30 UTC 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-05-17 20:52:34.632  INFO 1 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8086 (http)
2018-05-17 20:52:34.661  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2018-05-17 20:52:34.665  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.14
2018-05-17 20:52:34.873  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-05-17 20:52:34.873  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4752 ms
2018-05-17 20:52:35.206  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2018-05-17 20:52:35.220  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-17 20:52:35.221  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-17 20:52:35.222  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-17 20:52:35.222  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-17 20:52:36.727  INFO 1 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'd
efault'
2018-05-17 20:52:36.774  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: default
        ...]
2018-05-17 20:52:37.010  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2018-05-17 20:52:37.013  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-05-17 20:52:37.015  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2018-05-17 20:52:37.121  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2018-05-17 20:52:37.609  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2018-05-17 20:52:38.541  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Hibernate: drop table if exists users
Hibernate: create table users (id integer not null, name varchar(255), salary integer, team_name varchar(255), primary key (id))
2018-05-17 20:52:38.712  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2018-05-17 20:52:38.761  INFO 1 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-05-17 20:52:39.881  INFO 1 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.emb
edded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5b37e0d2: startup date [Thu May 17 20:52:30 UTC 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-05-17 20:52:40.089  INFO 1 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/all/create],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<c
om.techprimers.jpa.springdatajpahibernateexample.resource.Users> com.techprimers.jpa.springdatajpahibernateexample.resource.Resource.users()
2018-05-17 20:52:40.092  INFO 1 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/all/],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<com.tec
hprimers.jpa.springdatajpahibernateexample.resource.Users> com.techprimers.jpa.springdatajpahibernateexample.resource.Resource.all()
2018-05-17 20:52:40.103  INFO 1 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springfram
ework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.Ht
tpServletResponse)
2018-05-17 20:52:40.103  INFO 1 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEn
tity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-05-17 20:52:40.180  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.sprin
gframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-05-17 20:52:40.181  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframewo
rk.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-05-17 20:52:40.364  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.s
pringframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-05-17 20:52:41.108  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-05-17 20:52:41.230  INFO 1 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8086 (http)
2018-05-17 20:52:41.252  INFO 1 --- [           main] SpringDataJpaHibernateExampleApplication : Started SpringDataJpaHibernateExampleApplication in 12.225 seconds
(JVM running for 13.208)
```

Comment: Did your try waiting until the DB is fully initialized?

Comment: This is a situation which is called resilience which mean your app should handle the issue that the database not yet accessible...your health state should handle this as well...

Comment: @trust512 What do you mean by wait until DB is fully initialized? If DB isn't initialized, then we should see error when application start. In application log I see its creating db table and no other error related to that.

Comment: @khmarbaise How do I make sure that DB is not yet accessible? Looking at application start logs, DB is getting initialized fine. I have added application logs for reference.

Comment: Can this be an issue with Dockerfile (I mean do I need to run this inside some Linux e.g. FROM ubuntu:latest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was simple. Though everything is happening on windows, the underlying OS is Linux, so we have to replace localhost by ip address of linux machine of VM

so instead of hitting: http://localhost:8086/all/ 
I had to hit: http://192.168.99.100:8086/all/